# MongoDB/Mongoose error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I have a server running in HapiJS and until yesterday it was working, however today, when I went to run it, it returned the following error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> 
(C:\Projects\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:177:49)
at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect 
[MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
(node:4856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] 
on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

I've been working for hours trying to solve and so far I have not been successful

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you made sure that the mongo server is actually running?  What do your mongo logs say?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure to run `mongod` in the cmd. And another person with the same code, but on another computer is running the server

Comment: If they are on another server, why are you using `127.0.0.1`?  That's **your** IP (it's the loopback address).  You want to connect to **their** IP.

Comment: It was not me who created the server, we are working in team and with versioning, and this other person has exactly the same code as me, and is running perfectly on her machine, we are running separate code, each one on your machine

Comment: OK, then are you sure that mongo is listening on port `27017` on your machine?

Comment: I can access all dbs using cmd, but with the servirdor it does not access